# How to store the number of an iteration of a for next cycle

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table in a sheet.tabledata were I have insert certain data. Im using a **for next statament** to loop the elements of the table (and based on these values the code copy and paste from the table the address and tel number to that particular sheet)

I want to store in a variable the number of times that the **for next statment** loop in one sheet.

Because I want to create a condition that test:

**nroftimessofsheets(sheet1)** (which is 2 in this example, and I need to create a vairable to store this number) = **v_nrofForLoopinginsheet** (number of times that the **for statment** loop in that particular sheet, the second variable that I need)

In order, when the two variables are equal, I will instruct the code to do a particultar job before jumping to the next page.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: So your condition is: If all values of column "SheetName" are the same then do x else do y?

Comment: is more that I need to identify the moment that the for next go to the other sheet, (if I know that sheet1 appears 2 time and  if the loop is in the second iteration I know that the next iteration is for sheet2).